# Migrating email from Google apps to GoDaddy

Tags: email, webmail, godaddy

I had tried Google apps as how it works via a trail version of email. Hardly 2-3 accounts I created in trial version. I want to switch back to the email account on Go Daddy. Google apps email charges are expensive for me. I am new to all this and do not know what to set MX records to in GoDaddy in my account so that I can use emails on the GoDaddy servers and not on Google apps. These are all new accounts.

Answer (score 1):

The MX records are

```
0 – smtp.sercureserver.net
10 – mailstore1.secureserver.net
```

Perhaps this site can help.  https://au.godaddy.com/help/add-an-mx-record-19234

I found it via a google search :P